# MOSFET delay when on battery mode

Tags: mosfet

I made a 12 V UPS for a WiFi router and when changing to battery mode there is a slight delay and the router restarts.

I followed this schematic:

[image]
Image Source: [Instructables - DIY Mini UPS for WiFi Router V5.0](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Mini-UPS-for-WiFi-Router-V50/)

I used an IRF9540N MOSFET and on the schematic it's saying to use IRF9540 NON-N... not sure if that's the problem?
I checked every wire 100 times.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem - but what exactly is the board in the top-left? I hope it's some kind of lithium battery charger because a BMS is not a charger ...

Comment: ak1ca - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source webpage link & added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main rules. Thanks.

Comment: ak1ca - The fact that these are pre-built modules of unknown quality and without their schematics being included in your question, means there is no clear specification for how each one *should* behave :( Have you done any troubleshooting e.g. performed voltage measurements at the input & output of relevant modules during your testing? If so, please [edit] your question to add the test results and your analysis of them. If not, do you have a multimeter (and the experience to use it) to perform measurements?

Comment: Hello, I have multimeter and I did some basic troubleshooting, Im not expert btw. When switching to battery mode the voltage drops to 9v and goes back to 12v. I have multimeter can you please guide me what should I test ?

Comment: @ak1ca - Hi, "*When switching to battery mode the voltage drops to 9v and goes back to 12v.*" Please [edit] your question to add that detail & clearly state *which* voltage you mean (i.e. state where you were measuring). "*can you please guide me*" Unfortunately not, due to work commitments only allowing limited time here. Also, this is a Q&A site, not a forum, and a "hand-holding" interactive discussion is not a good fit for this site. If one of the site members wants to do that with you, it should be done in a chatroom (which we can setup), as it would likely reach the comment limit quickly.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. :D

Comment: one more question is there any difference between IRF9540 and IRF9540N ?